# QHD + 144Hz + G-Sync + HDR + IPS + 27“-32”?

Tags: displays

Are you aware of some displays meeting requirements mentioned in title? I was looking for a long while but couldn't find anything. Most panels with all mentioned features are 4k or miss HDR. Could you recommend me anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are G-Sync HDR equipped 1440p, IPS monitors that can ship to the UK today (I gleaned this off your profile). I could only find monitors that come with 165 Hz, but if it is an absolute necessity you have 144, you can set this in your operating system. The technical specs seems pretty much the same so take your pick of brand. Be ready to drop some serious cash if you want monitors with these exact specs.

### [£538.98 - ViewSonic - XG2703-GS](https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/product/c8zZxr/viewsonic-xg2703-gs-270-2560x1440-165hz-monitor-xg2703-gs)

### [£548.99 - AOC - AG271QG](https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/product/scM323/aoc-ag271qg-270-165hz-monitor-ag271qg)

### [£599.98 - Acer - XB271HU](https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/product/ttnG3C/acer-monitor-xb271hubmiprz)

### [£669.59 - Asus - PG279Q ROG](https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/product/XvfmP6/asus-monitor-pg279q)

For reference: [PC Part Picker query](https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/products/monitor/#H=144,240&r=256001440&p=1&A=1&sort=price&xcx=0)

Comment: The 165hz in most of these cases is probably/most certainly a 144hz panel with a factory overclock. Just a bit of information for the OP and anyone else visiting.